# Air native extensions FDT

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, mobile, air, fdt

I am using FDT 5 and trying to use IOS native extensions. I am pulling my hair out because every time I try running the application locally I get the following error:
"Not supported native extensions profile"

So I've tried scouring the web to find solutions and I've tried the following and these are the results:

- Renaming the ANE file to a SWC file and including it to the class path. Results: Nothing, same error
- Tried adding extendedDesktop. Results: Error changes to "invalid profile specified 'Application does not support current profile'"
- Tried manually adding the ane file to the class path. Results: Nothing

"Not supported native extensions profile" is the error that I just can't get around. Again, this is when I test locally in FDT (not on the device)

Comment: Sounds like an issue with FDT then because adding the native profile should have done it. My advice if you want to go native, uninstall FDT, download eclipse CDT and start writing real native apps in C++. :)

Comment: I just posted to your question on Adobe forums ;). I think you may just be doing something incorrect regarding ANE and not an FDT issue. Is the 'extendedDesktop' function available in mobile and are you experiencing the issue when running the app within the ADL? Where does this error happen? At runtime or compile time?

Comment: @AlanKlement Error happens at compile time. I haven't tried running the app in the ADL yet. Not sure about your question about extendedDesktop.

Comment: I've used mobile ANE for with FDT but I'm not an expert ( who is? ). All FDT is doing is passin the arguments to the compiler - no magic there. Do you have any other info which could help?

Comment: @AlanKlement are you on windows? could you by chance post a quick screencast of how you do it? it would be immensely helpful

Comment: I'm out of time today to help more, (I'll be back tomorrow), but check out these ANE examples by Patrick Kulling. He created them with FDT https://github.com/patrickkulling/Air-Mobile-Extensions

Comment: Still having issues? Have you tried Philipp's solution (below)?

Answer (score 3):

You need to change the namespace of your application discriptor to match your Air SDK:

```
<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/3.1">
```

Answer (score 2):

In your application descriptor file, remove "desktop" from the list of supported profiles.

For instance, change

```
<supportedProfiles>desktop extendedDesktop mobileDevice</supportedProfiles>
```

to

```
<supportedProfiles>extendedDesktop mobileDevice</supportedProfiles>
```

This will alleviate the "Not supported native extensions profile" error.

Comment: Unfortunately it also disables Updater.isSupported when running on the desktop. It would be nice if there was another way to ignore the native extensions without losing this feature or modifying the app.xml with every compile.